# deploying azure function using custom image

Tags: python, docker, azure-functions

I am developing an azure app function that will be using a custom image with docker.

This is my DockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.7

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

# Adding "apt-get install make" here
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install make && apt-get install -y gcc g++ && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install numpy 
RUN pip install pandas 
RUN pip install scipy 

RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz


COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt 

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

Everything works fine when I am using my local docker desktop app.
When I am trying to deploy to azure using the VS-Code build it interface the docker file fails to build here is the output I get:

```
14:57:08 :   building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
14:57:08 :   creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
14:57:08 :   creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib
14:57:08 :   gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib/include -I/tmp/pip-install-rgqyohyf/ta-lib/.eggs/numpy-1.21.2-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include -I/opt/python/3.7.9/include/python3.7m -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/talib/_ta_lib.o
14:57:08 :   talib/_ta_lib.c:613:28: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_defs.h: No such file or directory
14:57:08 :    #include "ta-lib/ta_defs.h"
14:57:08 :                               ^
14:57:08 :   compilation terminated.
14:57:09 :   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
14:57:09 :   ----------------------------------------
14:57:09 :   ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-Lib
14:57:09 : DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for TA-Lib which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
14:57:16 : [11:57:16+0000]     Running setup.py install for TA-Lib: started
14:57:16 : [11:57:16+0000]     Running setup.py install for TA-Lib: finished with status 'error'
14:57:16 :     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

I am not sure what to make of this error and why it works fine in docker.

Thanks

Amit

Comment: As per the error message-" DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for TA-Lib which do not use PEP 517" which means it may deprecated. So try to change the version from 20.3 to 21.0.you can refer the below link which may help.

https://github.com/freqtrade/freqtrade/issues/4245

Comment: @RajkumarMamidiChettu-MT change what from version 20.3 to 21.0?